# CSS hover menu not working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive navigation bar in css. I want text when the width of the screen is large enough and a drop down box when it is below a certain width. The responsiveness is kicking in, but the hover feature is not working. I just want a drop down menu when hovering

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cjbruin/rnmg5gjb/

And code

HTML

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">News</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px" class="icon">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .topnav a {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .icon:hover .topnav a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Comment: But if you use hover you won't be able to keep its active state, you might want to look for a click. Is this doing what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/rnmg5gjb/4/

Comment: When you hover over the icon, currently your not doing anything other than changing it to black and the "display: block" for the hover does nothing. Your going to want to display another div which contains the text and styling for the dropdown to appear when hovered

Comment: difficult to tell what you're asking, but `.icon:hover .topnav a` is not a correct selector.  There is no `.topnav` descendant of `.icon`.  You'll need to add the hover state to `.topnav` instead.  Does this do what you were trying to accomplish? https://jsfiddle.net/yswdtg0e/

Comment: Joseph Merikle Yes that is what I am trying to do

Comment: John Batts Thanks I'll try that

Answer (score 1):

```
.icon:hover .topnav a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
  }
```

This code is the problem, .icon is inside .topnav class.

CSS Rules:

**X Y  :Selects all children(Y) .. this is the one you are using**

**X~Y  :Selects all Y`s next to X**

so there are many solution to your problem

1.

```
.icon:hover .topnav a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
  }
```

change this to following

```
.icon:hover ~ a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rnmg5gjb/5/

2. Take .icon class outside and use .icon:hover .topnav a